# how to get tag of dynamically created linear layout and it's child ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, dynamic

Parent_LinearLayout

```
        LinearLayout
             TextView
             LinearLayout
```

I have a parent Linear layout in the XML. 
I created a Linear layout dynamically and whose child are TextView and A linear layout.
I added this layout to the Parent linear layout.

Now my question is how to get the Tag of Linear Layout(4th) and the Tag of its child (which i will add later dynamically).

```
for(int i=0;i<parent_Layout.getChildCount();i++){
                    View v=parent_Layout.getChildAt(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+parent_Layout.getChildCount() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

am trying to do something like this, but am not getting any idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `setTag()` on layouts...and later retrieve the layout using `getTag()`.Hope that helps.